# The array passed as the value prop to the Context provider (at line 8) changes every render. How i can fix this?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

I am using context and HOC. I am passing the state internally via context to the HOC and it throws an error like this. You need to add useMemo. But I have no idea how exactly to do it. Can anyone tell me how can I fix this please.   8:32  error  The array passed as the value prop to the Context provider (at line 8) changes every render. To fix this consider wrapping it in a useMemo hook  react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values

This is my HOC

```
function ModalProvider({ children }) {
const [context, setContext] = useState(false);
return (
<MyContext.Provider value={[context, setContext]}>
  {children}
</MyContext.Provider>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useMemo like this

```
const contextMemo = useMemo( () => context ), [context]
```

And then use contextMemo instead of context
What this is basically doing is saying only get the new value of contextMemo when context changes